# Prevent Error on mysql_connect() - Access denied

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, mysql-connect

I have this code snippet:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $usr, $pwd);
```

How can I prevent PHP from printing an error message when MySQL access is denied?

I need exactly this syntax but nothing works for me.

I tried `$conn = mysql_connect($host, $usr, $pwd) or false;` and `$conn = mysql_connect($host, $usr, $pwd) || false;` and the following:

```
try {
    $conn = mysql_connect($host, $usr, $pwd);

    if(!$conn) {
        throw new Exception('Failed');
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    // ...
}
```

PHP always prints an error message that the connection failed. But I just want to return false, if it failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why you want to, but you can add a `@` to surpress php errors?

see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: Thanks, that's it! :) Didn't know that before.

Answer (score 10):

Error printing should not be activated on a production server. Consider changing your php.ini configuration to log error instead of displaying it.

Using @ to silent error message is not a good solution.

Comment: +1: People need to **stop** spattering `@` everywhere. Configure your error levels properly instead.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't really be using `mysql_connect` in PHP 5, as its now deprecated in favour of mysqli and PDO.

But you can probably silence the warning generated by `mysql_connect` by prefixing with `@`:

`@mysql_connect()`

Answer (score 0):

The `@`  suppresses errors.  And also set error reporting `error_reporting(0);` to turn off all errors. Also check out [`mysqli`](http://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php&ei=JYt4TrqHC8X64QT-m_D-Cw&usg=AFQjCNEqr4MIMr-la3jWWjZ1PQbJFnyFHw)

[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Don't turn off your error reporting. Instead you should configure display_errors and log_errors in your php.ini.